# Recover GNU Ring password

Tags: gnu-ring

I need to generate a new PIN to link my GNU Ring account to another device, but I can not remember the correct password. Is there a procedure to recover or reset my password?

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortinately [not possible](https://lists.libreplanet.org/archive/html/jami/2018-08/msg00008.html) to recover a password from GNU Jami (formerly GNU Ring).

You will have to make a new account.